How to implement `others` for a Django Model Choices-CharField?
I have a Django model that has several CharFields. A lot of these represent information of the type

Item Type 1
Item Type 2
Others

The usual way of defining choices for a CharField is
            models.CharField(
            max_length=255,
            choices=ChoiceList.choices, # Defining Choices
        )

As you would have guessed, this fails to meet my requirements since I cannot pass it anything(Others) apart from the pre-defined choices.
I cannot discard the choices parameter since I need the model to have the choices information for each field. This will be used to fetch all legal options for a particular field.
I tried using a custom validator function
def validate_choice(value, choices):
    if value == "Others:":
        print(value, choices)
    valid_choices = [choice[0] for choice in choices]
    if not value.startswith("Others:") and value not in valid_choices:
        raise ValidationError(f"{value} is not a valid choice")


(For simplicity, I defined my logic as

Either the value is in the Choice List
Or it starts with Others: (To indicate that it is a deliberate Other value)

And subsequently, I modified the CharField as follows, to use the new Validator Function
        models.CharField(
            max_length=255,
            choices=IPCSections.choices,
            validators=[partial(validate_choice, choices=ChoiceList.choices)],
        )

I then noticed that The Choice validation (By Django) happens before the custom validator is called. Which, again leads the the same issue
Others:% is not a valid choice

Looking up in the Django Documentation, I found methods like
model.clean()
model.clean_all() etc.

I tried overriding these methods, but did not end up with anything useful and the documentation does not cover exactly in what order and when are they called.
